# how can i upload cakePHP framework project on IPAGE hosting server?

Tags: php, cakephp

this is my web site http://uncommonw.com/ build using cakephp framework is a PHP framework , i want to know what is the error ?
thanks

Comment: How are we supposed to know? And what has the title got to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it; the directory /var/php_sessions/ doesn't exist or isn't writeable by CakePHP

```
failed: No such file or directory
....
....
Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting 
of session.save_path is correct (/var/php_sessions)
```

However, I think you can fix this issue by using 'Cake' as session handler in stead of 'php';

In your app/Config/core.php, change this:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

To:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

Sessions will then be written to this directory inside your app folder:

```
app/tmp/sessions
```

You will have to make sure that the tmp directory (and all folders inside it) are writeable for PHP

Comment: thank you very much . it working now properly , but  i have new problem ,URL not working well ,and JS file and CSS Files cann't be loaded , i think the solution at .htaccess . all links redirect to the home page .

Comment: @MahmoudR.Ebeed I don't think I'll be able to help you out further and StackOverflow is not the location for that. I gave you a solution for the error you were having, which is now apparently solved, but debugging a website for you, without any knowledge about it's workings whatsoever is not the purpose of this site. Please mark this question as solved and, if you have a new specific problem, post a new question. Be sure to be specific and include the relevant parts of your code and mention *what you have tried so far*